# Elasticsearch Node.js client throws parsing_exception: [parsing_exception] Reason: unknown query [query]

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to develop a `scroll` routine in order to process some elements stored in `Elasticsearch` using `Node.js` — specifically `@elastic/elasticsearch` version `8.2.1`.

This is what I have with so far:

```js
async function* scrollSearch(query) {
  let response = await client.search({
    index: "my.elasticsearch.index",
    query: JSON.parse(query),
    scroll: "1m",
    size: 100,
    // sort: [{ modification_date: "desc", }],
    // track_total_hits: true,
  });
  while (true) {
    const sourceHits = response.hits.hits;
    if (sourceHits.length === 0) {
      break;
    }
    for (const hit of sourceHits) {
      yield hit;
    }
    if (!response._scroll_id) {
      break;
    }
    response = await client.scroll({
      scroll_id: response._scroll_id,
      scroll: "10s",
    });
  }
}
```

For the time being I'm just debugging this, so I'm invoking the previous function directly:

```js
const query = `
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "status": "THE_STATUS"
            }
          },
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "object1.field1"
            }
          },
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "object2.field1"
            }
          },
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "object2.field2"
            }
          },
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "object3.field1"
            }
          },
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "object3.field2"
            }
          },
          {
            "exists": {
              "field": "object3.field3"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
`;
for await (const hit of scrollSearch(query)) {
  console.log(hit._source);
}
```

I'm always getting the following error with that query:

```bash
 ResponseError: parsing_exception: [parsing_exception] Reason: unknown query [query]
  at SniffingTransport.request (node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:476:27)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async Client.SearchApi [as search] (node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/api/search.js:65:12)
  at async scrollSearch (file:///Users/x80486/Workshop/debug-tool/src/elasticsearch.service.js:15:18)
  at async Context.<anonymous> (file:///Users/x80486/Workshop/debug-tool/test/my.test.js:132:22)
```

On the other hand, if I use the exact same query in the `Dev Tools` interface, I'm getting the expected results back:

```
POST my.elasticsearch.index/_search?scroll=1m
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "THE_STATUS"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "object1.field1"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "object2.field1"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "object2.field2"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "object3.field1"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "object3.field2"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "object3.field3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "_scroll_id" : "the scroll id value",
  "took" : 266,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "successful" : 12,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to know which part of the query is not understood by the `Node.js` client or in general to validate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, well...I just needed to remove the `query` object/segment. This is how it must be:

```js
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "status": "THE_STATUS"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "object1.field1"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "object2.field1"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "object2.field2"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "object3.field1"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "object3.field2"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "object3.field3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, since you have it already on line 4 ;-)